# How to use positional parameters in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How does one use positional / unnamed parameters in SQLAlchemy?
This doesn't work..
I know named parameters work but sometimes I prefer unnamed parameters.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.engine.create_engine('mysql://py:123@localhost/py', echo=True)
con = engine.connect()
res = con.execute(text("select uid, name from users where uid = ?"), 1);
```

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/olaf/py/./test.py", line 10, in <module>
    res = con.execute(text("select uid, torrent_pass from xbt_users where uid = ?"), 1);
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1090, in _execute_clauseelement
    keys = list(distilled_params[0].keys())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'```
````

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the query in `text` is breaking your code, you need to adjust the syntax. Here is an example from the documentation https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=text#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text

```
t = text("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:user_id")
result = connection.execute(t, user_id=12)
```

Below you will find a working version of your code:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import text
>>> s = text("select uid, name from users where uid = :uid")
>>> conn.execute(s, uid=1).first()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use like that:

```
res = con.execute(
    "SELECT uid, name from users where uid = %s", 1)
```